# How to resize a JQuery/Datatable after hiding columns

Tags: jquery, resize, width, datatables

i'm using the DataTables plugin for JQuery, my problem basically lies in the fact that my datatable has to many columns and (visually) gets out of the bounds of its container (a div tag). I then hide some of the columns that are, at this point, irrelevant. But the width of the table just does not resize it self (let's say to its parent's witdh). I tried using the

```
fnAdjustColumnSizing()
```

function after creating the datatable but it doesn't seems to work (i also tried redrawing the table with fnDraw()). I tried as well to give some initial parameters in order to get a smaller size on each column

```
$("#reportTable").dataTable({"aoColumns":[{sWidth:"10%"},{sWidth:"10%"},{sWidth:"10%"}]});
```

but it throws an error since i have to "turn on" the bRetrieve parameter (which i did later on, but it didn't work, it just prevent the error to popup).
So... tecnically i want to make my datatable smaller after some columns are hidden.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error was about that the datatable could not be reinitialized because the datatable was already there and i was passing some new parameters, i just passed bRetrieve as true (bDestroy worked as well) because I was saving the state of the datatable in a javascript var. This was not the real solution nor the problem.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The solution was actually simpler than I thought. Using the "inspect element" feature in google chrome I found that, when calling "datatable()" datatables's method, datatables API used a fixed width based on the space needed to display the amount of columns. It was something like 1947 pixels or so. Therefore, you cannot change this using simple css because the fixed width used by datatables had higher priority. 
The solution I found was using "width" jquery's method after hiding the columns:

```
$("#reportTable").width("100%");
```

since it changes the width attribute directly in the table element.

Comment: I've been struggling on this for hours. Thanks a lot ! BTW, works fine with `$table.width('auto');` if you don't want your table to fill its container. The only thing is to overload the previous calculated width.

Comment: This helped me with some unexpected behavior after hiding a column. ty

Answer (score 1):

It is work for me as has been mentioned by OlivierH:

```js
$('#your_datatable_selector').width('auto');
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the width of columns in datatables I give the columns different classes using the sClass parameter and then set the width using css.

If a column is in the data but you don't want it visible, set bVisible to false and it will not render the column rather than try to hide it after render.

Comment: Does it work even if I don't know exactly the number of columns my table is having? my table is dynamically created by retrieving data from different SQL queries, therefore i cannot be sure of how many columns my table is made of. I already tried this but it doesn't seems to hide any columns.